# create a web service from a html page: client side, how can i get result and not the code souce of the page

Tags: html, web-services

I'm trying to do the following thing:
I wanted to get two dynamic data (latitude and longitude) from a page.html  located in a web server I want to get them as a web service:
Here is the result of the execution of my web page situated in the server:
{"results": [{"Latitude": "36.81881", "Longitude": "10.16596"}]}
And that is exactly what I wanted to recover in my client application but the problem is that I can’t get the result, I can only get the code source of the page. Html located in the server.
Here is the method that I used on the client to get data from server :

```
function latLong()
{

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET","http://localhost/AtitLongiWebService.html",true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){
     alert(ajax.responseText);    
 }
     }
}
```

Here is my page.html in the web server:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function startWatch(){
      if (navigator.geolocation)
        var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback,
                                  errorCallback,
                                  {enableHighAccuracy:true,
                                  timeout:10000,
                                  maximumAge:0});
      else
        alert("Votre navigateur ne prend pas en compte la géolocalisation HTML5");
    }

    function stopWatch(){
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
    }     

    function successCallback(position){
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
      document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
    };  

    function errorCallback(error){
      switch(error.code){
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          alert("L'utilisateur n'a pas autorisé l'accès à sa position");
          break;      
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          alert("L'emplacement de l'utilisateur n'a pas pu être déterminé");
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          alert("Le service n'a pas répondu à temps");
          break;
        }
    };

  </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startWatch()">

        {"results":[{"Latitude":"<label id="lat"></label>",
        "Longitude": "<label id="long"></label>"}]}


    </body>
</html>
```

Usually ajax.responseText returns the result but in this case it returns the code source, can someone help me to get the result of the execution of the page and not the code source. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are expecting javascript to be run on the server-side. Is this the case, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: yes, i want to run javascript on the server-side and it works fine but i can't get the result in the client side

Comment: Unless you have something special setup to tell your http server to run the javascript itsself then it will just send it out to run on the client. If you want the server to be performing the computations shouldn't you be using something like PHP?

Comment: In fact I need latitude and longitude of the web server and it's very easy and simple to recover with html5 and javascript, which is why I migrated to html5 despite I'm working on the server side. It is much more complicated with php

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So, what web server (software) are you using on your server (machine)?

Answer (score 0):

At present the webpage you are accessing is a standard static HTML page with embedded javascript. As this is being served up by Apache (as part of the WAMPserver environment) it is treating it as a plain HTML page with *client side* javascript. That is, just sending the file to the client without running anything it.

In order to run *server-side* javascript you need to have a [javascript server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions), such as [node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).